# Call SelectedDateChanged event with custom event args by will?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, datepicker

I have a **System.Windows.Controls.DatePicker** (**name = "rMethod"**) component and when I set from outside its value, this event gets called:

```
private void rMetod_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
```

I have double duty for this date picker. When there as a date in the table I want to fill this date picker from the database. And when there is no date data, I want this date picker to be able to save the chosen date to the database.

However, my INSERT SQL command gets called even when there is a date data in the table, which results in duplicate key SQL exception, since the same event gets called when I use this statement:

```
rMethod.Text = "10/10/1970"
```

How can I call the **SelectedDateChanged** with custom args and be able to resolve the right action, i.e. if there is no date data in the table saved previosly, the INSERT should be executed, and when there is, just run SELECT command or fill this date picker with a prefetched value?

Comment: Implement your logic in rMetod_SelectedDateChanged, i.e. check whether there already is a record in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you're heading the wrong way. `EventArgs` aren't supposed to be instantiated manually, and event handlers arent supposed to be called manually. 
Instead of clinging to `SelectionChangedEventArgs`, and `DatePicker`, move your logic to some method that can handle both cases.

For example, you can have some global flag that takes care of that date.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    bool dateExists = false;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

When you're fetching data from database, if date exists, set flag to true, like this

```
if (reader["Date"] != DbNull.Value)
    dateExists = true;
```

later, in your insert method, you can check your flag and depending on it set date.

```
if (!dateExists) //there was no date in database
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", DateTime.Now);
else
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", rMethod.SelectedDate);
```

I hope you understand this approach.